# How do I create a multiple selection for a field in Wordpress Theme from Templatic?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this website : http://aisiel.ro - a real estate agency website

Below the slider is the search field where we the the area called "Zona" - Area in English.

From here the user can select but only one area of search, whereas I want to be able to select multiple areas for the user to get results of more than one field.:)

I am not very good at php, but i'm working my way through, so what can I do ?

Comment: I would like to mention that the wordpress theme is Real Estate- from Templatic... and their indian assistance sucks :" I've received an answer like : we are sorry but your problem will need additional coding. it is not our job to do that .." :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to add the `multiple` attribute to the Zona `select` tag. For example:

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="value">Value</option>
    // More options
</select>
```

Because of the different ways of doing this, and because you have to inform the user that multiple selection is available, it is more user-friendly to use checkboxes instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's a wordpress template.... :) I need somehow to edit search.php and searchform.php files to do that. :(

Comment: Is there not a search.php or searchform.php in the theme directory?

Comment: yes the are. wp includes more exactly. but somehow I have to edit those files and I haven't got a clue what to edit be cause it is not simple html, to perform this task.

Comment: If I can see the searchform.php I might be able to help. Paste the file to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and I'll take a look.

Comment: This is the first file the indian help dude said I would have to edit : http://pastebin.com/Hm9RYjhr and this is the second file : http://pastebin.com/fry8FHu8  The first file i've pasted is not the good one . Sorry and many many thanks !

Comment: You need to edit http://pastebin.com/Hm9RYjhr On line 91 change `<select name="srch_location" id="srch_location" onchange="" class="fl select">` to `<select name="srch_location" id="srch_location" onchange="" class="fl select" multiple>`

Comment: In "Zona" I want to be able to select more than one field..... :) :) Thanks a lot :) ... but how do I do it ? I have already modified what you have given me :)

Comment: Nothing mainly happens... and you can check by yourself the website :) ! http://www.aisiel.ro

Comment: are you still there ? ? ? ?

Comment: The changes haven't been applied! If you look at the site in Chrome, right click on the Zona dropdown and Inspect Element you will see that the `multiple` attribute hasn't been added. The changes I have said should work unless another file is overriding it. Without knowing the structure of the theme it's hard to pinpoint what needs changing.

Comment: OK. Here is the answer of the indian assstance : 1. Search.php: RealEstate/Library/Includes
2. post_functions.php: RealEstate/Monetize/General

In the second file you will be able to see the code at around line number 561. A function is there: search_custom_post_field($custom_metaboxes). This is responsible for displaying the filed on the search form. You can edit the coding in to this function as per your requirements. " The change you've said I've addend into search.php.  I will again paste post_functions.php... And Again Thank YOU !! ! ! !!

Comment: I've looked through the files you provide and the changes I suggested should work. Make sure you are editing the correct files, I have added the edited file to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2UXkzs8t), are you sure it is search.php, not searchform.php? If that doesn't work then I can't help you any further. Sorry! I hope you find a solution soon.

Comment: thanks a lot.. It doesn't work... but again thanks for the help !